# enable clicking on links in webview

Tags: objective-c, macos

How do I enable clicking on links in my mac osx webview?

I have the following code but I don't know what methods to implement for the policy delegate...

```
@synthesize myWebView = _myWebView;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification


    /* webview setup here, everything works fine 
    except cannot click links in webview..... */


    //setup my delegate
    _myWebView.policyDelegate = self;

}
//Now what?....
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

WebView doesn't have restriction on links.

But if you need a custom behavior when clicking on a link in your web view, you should implement "webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:" in your policy delegate. Then you you get the action type from the action information dictionary and you do your custom behavior if it's a link clicked event.

Example:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame  decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener

{

    NSUInteger actionType = [[actionInformation objectForKey:WebActionNavigationTypeKey] unsignedIntValue];
    if (actionType == WebNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        //Do your stuff
    } else {
        [listener use];
    }

}
```

Comment: My app is opening a gmail window. It won't let me click links that are in my emails. Looks like it does work for other webpages. I need to figure out how to enable links in gmail.

Comment: Check if you have javascript errors in the console. It might be a Google's end issue.

Comment: You need to also add the delegate method decidePolicyForNewWindowAction